# React: background not changing when rerendering

Tags: reactjs, background-image, render

I am new to React and what I want is my component to change the background image. I am passing the source URL in the props but the background image does not change and remains the same when re-rendering.

```
export default class MovieItem extends Component {
  posterSrc = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.props.movieDetails.poster_path}`;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="movie-item-cont">
          <div
            className="movie-image-cont"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.posterSrc})` }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't want to create a div and insert the image into it but change the background image only. I know it has to be done using refs, but it is also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that `posterSrc` to be recalculated on render when props change you need to keep it inside the `render` method.

Like this:

```
export default class MovieItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const posterSrc = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${this.props.movieDetails.poster_path}`;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="movie-item-cont">
          <div
            className="movie-image-cont"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.posterSrc})` }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This way you'll adopt React's lifecycle methods as intended.